# Hiding a form from user in c# windows application

Tags: c#

I have form, which i dont want the user to see it. "Dont ask me why :)"

I am using the following to achive it.

```
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1, 1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "Logout";
        this.Opacity = 0;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Text = "Logout";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

But, when i press Alt + Tab it is showing the form in the list. 
I want to hide that too from the user.
Possible ? How ? Thanks.

Okay, okay guys....i can share why... This is a logout form. Since the requirement is like logging out of application when the user pressed ctrl + Alt + Q, i need to use the KeyPress event handler which can be done only in a windows form. So i used a invisible form to achieve this. Got it..:) Thanks. Now please help me on this.

Comment: If you don't want the user to view the form then why are you opening it?

Comment: Sounds like malware! And therefore, it would be natural to ask "Why?"

Comment: "Dont ask me why :)". We just have to ask...why?

Comment: @ThePower: Do you mean why shouldn't we ask him "Why?" ? ;-)

Comment: @ Cerebrus: It's a double whammy, Why should we not ask why? And why?

Comment: Okay, okay guys....i can share why...

This is a logout form. Since the requirement is like logging out of application when the user pressed ctrl + Alt + Q, i need to use the KeyPress event handler which can be done only in a windows form.
So i used a invisible form to achieve this.

Got it..:)  Thanks.

Now please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hide Form from Alt+Tab](http://www.csharp411.com/hide-form-from-alttab/)

Ultimate question:

**Why do you need this?**

Comment: Okay, okay guys....i can share why...

This is a logout form. Since the requirement is like logging out of application when the user pressed ctrl + Alt + Q, i need to use the KeyPress event handler which can be done only in a windows form.
So i used a invisible form to achieve this.

Got it..:)  Thanks.

Now please help me on this.